# finding duplicate records in sql server table

Tags: sql-server

I know this is a very common questions and it has been answere and asked on stackoverlow tons of times, I have a same situtation but with a small catch

I am trying to use group by clause to get the duplicates and if they exists make an update and if they don't just do an insert

```
SELECT      name,age,sex, COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM        CUSTOMER
GROUP BY    name,age,sex;
```

there is also a field called as `datecreated` which holds currenttimestamp and it is different for every record and even for duplicates

how can i create a query which will will hold off this and that if all the above has a `cnt` greater than `1` , just do an `update` and else do an `insert`

Comment: Hint: Try to use `MERGE`

Comment: Update insert = [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql).  Why would you do an insert if count = 1? wouldn't you want cnt >0 to do an update and = 0 to do an insert?

Comment: is there no ID field? Like CustomerID whcih is unique to each customer? And what are you inserting? What would the update be?

Comment: yes, no unique indexes has been defined,and we cannot define because same user can have different other items associated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this for finding duplicates.
If rn > 1 means it is duplicate then update else insert.

```
Select name,age,sex from 
(SELECT name,age,sex, row_number() over (partition by name,age,sex order by name) rn
FROM CUSTOMER) as a
Where a.rn > 1       ---- for finding duplicate records
```

**EDIT**

As your requirements are different check if it is working or not.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE name = 'your_value1' and age ='your_value2' and sex = 'your_value3')
UPDATE CUSTOMER set name = 'your_value1',age ='your_value2',sex = 'your_value3'
where name = 'your_value1' 
and age ='your_value2' 
and sex = 'your_value3'
ELSE 
insert into CUSTOMER(name,age,sex) VALUES ('Your_value1','your_value2','your_value3')
```

Comment: Can you provide me with a complete code example where it will wrap the else condition if this, do that else do this

Comment: Use this query inside if exist then update else insert

Comment: please elaborate, i am very new

Comment: What you want to insert or update ? Which fields ? Give some idea about this so that I can help.

Comment: name,age,sex - if they exists with same value i am inserting, they should update and if one of them differs, it should insert a new record